# Elastic Search : Applying Filter on nested segments and returning only those segments

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a customer info with orders in Elastic Search in the following format

```
{
  "_index": “customer_domain_r4",
  "_type": “CustomerData”,
  "_id": "6fff6ce8-e792-4047-b636-a1dda0aa2b72",
  "_version": 173,
  "_score": 3.551258,
  "_source": {
    “first”: "John",
    “last”: "Doe",
    “dateOfBirth”: null,
    "primaryPhone": "6154525131",
    “customerOrders”: [
      {
        “orders”: [
          {
            “orderNumber": 1,
            “orderName": “Grocery”,
            "recordVersion": 1,
            "createdDateTimeGmt": "May 09, 2018 03:19:11 PM",
            "deletedDateTimeGmt": "May 12, 2018 08:28:42 PM",
            "createdSessionTokenId": "PUWzJmipCIyvciMDEr3IfhXuV3Gx",
            "updatedSessionTokenId": "1234567890",
            "lastUpdatedDateTimeGmt": "May 12, 2018 08:28:48 PM",
            “orderType”: “Online”   
            "id": "8e2973e3-b43b-4430-b6d7-7c24846e9bba"
          },
          {
            “orderNumber": 2,
            “orderName": “Medications”,
            "recordVersion": 1,
            "createdDateTimeGmt": "May 09, 2018 03:19:11 PM",
            "deletedDateTimeGmt": null,
            "createdSessionTokenId": "PUWzJmipCIyvciMDEr3IfhXuV3Gx",
            "updatedSessionTokenId": "1234567890",
            "lastUpdatedDateTimeGmt": "May 12, 2018 08:28:48 PM",
            “orderType”: “Offline”  
            "id": "8e2973e3-b43b-4430-b6d7-7c2665e9bba"
          }
]
}
```

Now my requirement is to fetch only orders of a certain type for a given customer id. The query i ran

```
{"index":"customer_domain_r4","type":"CustomerData"}
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"id":"6fff6ce8-e792-4047-b636-a1dda0aa2b72"}},{"nested":{"path":"customerOrders","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"customerOrders. orderType":"Online"}}]}}}}]}},"_source":{"includes":["customerOrders"],"excludes":[]}}
```

The above query returns all the orders of the customer because the criteria looks for any customer which has an order of type online. I am looking for the query to return only orders of customer 6fff6ce8-e792-4047-b636-a1dda0aa2b72 of type online.

Is there a way i can directly add criteria for the includes section.

If not i have to filter this in the java middle tier section